# Python 3 conditional variable selection increment

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm currently working on a project where a lot of different accounting is done and I came to see this pattern very often:

```
if A > X:
    B += 1
else:
    C += 1
```

I know ternary operator but if I understand it correctly the shortest way how to utilize it would be:

```
B += 1 if A > X else False
C += 1 if A <= X else False
```

since ternary operator is connected to the variable used in its head. So using ternary operator is obviously worse than the previous `if/else` both from computational and readability standpoint.

The other idea was to create a simple function like this:

```
conditional_bumper(positive_case_var, negative_case_var, condition_var, compare_to=0)
```

then the usage looks like:

```
conditional_bumper(B, C, A, X)  # X being optional
```

so I can one line it every time I see it but at the same time this seems to me like a very 'hacky' solution. Is there a better way I don't see?

Comment: Whats wrong with the original pattern?

Comment: Also you should not use ternary side effects to do assignment.
If you have two vars, then a ternary is not the correct pattern. It is like using `switch true`.
In the second code you are just making everything harder to read.

Comment: Imo readability wins over "one-liners".

Comment: @Sayse Nothing in terms of functionality or readability but at certain files handling various statistics and accounting it might be 5-10% of the code which makes it annoying at least for me. :P

Comment: Seems like you are counting the number of times that `A > X`. If this is a case, there is probably a way you can utilize `collections.Counter`

Comment: If you don't care about readability at all, you could write this even shorter as `B += A > X; C += A <= X` - your second code block is relying on the fact that `False` has a numeric value of 0, might as well rely on `True` having a value of 1 as well.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I agree with ternary part, I don't understand the second part.

Comment: @DeepSpace I'll check that out but I think the problem will be that it is not always some list I iterate over, but sometimes a function which is called (even) from different places at different times and has this part in it.

Comment: @jasonharper Interesting idea, the problem I see is 2x evaluating the same condition and technically using 2 lines if properly spaced (if I'm correctly understanding).

Comment: Could you group the `B` and `C` together somehow in list or a dict? Then `V[0 if A>X else 1] += 1`. The indices/keys `0` and `1` can be adjusted if need be.

Comment: @VPfB Using `0 if A>X else 1` is a bit counter-intuitive (especially if treating `0` as the "truthy" case) since booleans can be used as keys directly. See my answer

Comment: @DeepSpace I added the disclaimer that it can be adjusted. I agree with the "truthy" case, but you can also consider it as the first and the second item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this Pal!** Hope this gives you a north of this matter. Cheers!

```py
    # declare and initialize variables
    B, C = 0, 0
    A, X = 1, 2
    
    # ternary operator to work with this conditional
    B,C = (B + 1, C) if A > X else(B,C + 1)
    
    #display results
    print(B,C)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems as the best option so far. :)

Comment: Glad to be of help, pal!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the more readable you'r code is, the better is. " One line " code works but it's not viable

Comment: I agree with you, I don't want to sacrifice readability I simply wonder if I can get better solution overall because in a way having that original pattern in the code makes it long and less readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really after a one-liner and don't care about readability (which you shouldn't), you can use this old trick (at the cost of building a list and having a somewhat cryptic code)

```
A = 2
B = 0
C = 0
X = 3

CB = [C, B]
print(CB)
CB[A > X] += 1
print(CB)

# [0, 0]
# [1, 0]
```

Note that `C` and `B` themselves are not modified, the change is only visible through the `CB` list.

This works because `A > X` evaluates to `True` or `False`, which can be used for indexing since `bool` subclasses `int`.

### A better approach using a dict

Another less cryptic option is to use a `dict` instead. I think this is actually a better option. You can even use meaning full names :)

```
A = 2
X = 3

times_a_greater_than_x = {True: 0, False: 0}
times_a_greater_than_x [A > X] += 1
print(times_a_greater_than_x )
# {True: 0, False: 1}
```

Comment: I appreciate the creativity of these! :) It could even scale up for more conditions and vars if certain ordering was followed but in that case I would have to accept that someone would kill me eventually (and rightly so).

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing the idea of using a function:

```
def inc_if(condition, true_var, false_var):
    if condition:
        true_var += 1
    else:
        false_var += 1

    return (true_var, false_var)


B, C = inc_if(A > X, B, C)
```

This is quite readable because it can be read from left to right as "increment if A > X" followed by the variable that would be in the if clause and at last the variable from the else clause.

The variables need to be returned by the function and reassigned, unless global variables are used.

Comment: Good improvement, the reassignment is necessary as you point out. Sadly it also makes it computationally more expensive hence it seems that staying with the original is the only reasonable course of action.

Answer (score 1):

If X varies across the conditionals but `A`, `B`, and `C` remain the same, you can refactor to a simple loop.

```py
for X in (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 23):
    if A > X:
        B += 1
    else:
        C += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this isn't one line, but you can increment each variable by the increment times the boolean expression

```py
inc = 1
B += inc * (A > X)
C += inc * (A < X)
```

or you can use this

```py
inc = 1
B += inc * (A > X); C += inc * (A < X)
```

Comment: Two tests instead of one, two assignment instead of one, two multiplications instead of none .... not an improvement IMO